# How to enable processfork for unit tests in Gradle Android plugin

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle

I have configured unit testing for AndroidStudio as described on the Android documentation (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support).

I would like to run every test method in its own JVM, so all static properties in my project are set back to their default values.

I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation and I'm afraid this is not possible yet.

I'm running my tests from the command line (`gradlew --daemon test`) as I didn't get the testrunner in Android Studio to work.

Does anyone know how to fork every testmethod in its own jvm process, so they run 'standalone'? Please let me know if this is possible or if there are alternative ways to run every testmethod in it's own process using gradle.

Comment: Got the internal test runner of Android Studio to work by doing a clean build from Android Studio itself and run the test afterwards. But still I cannot get processfork to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats easy. In your test task set

```
forkEvery 1
```

That will cause a new jvm to be forked for every single test.